Print a list of lists row wise in Haskell
I'm trying to print a list of lists in Haskell. It's something I've successfully done before for two sub lists but I can't remember all the steps and I haven't seen something for an arbitrary number of sub-lists. The list is of type [[Double]] where all sub-lists are of equal length.
With input [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] the output should be
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

My idea thus far is using mapM_. I would like to control the print using something like printf. However, this prints sub-list by sub-list, not index by index.
import Text.Printf ( printf )

print_row :: Double -> IO ()
print_row r = do
    printf "%9.6f" r

print_rows :: [[Double]] -> Int -> IO ()
print_rows r i = do
    mapM_ print_row (r !! i)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let rs = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
        n  = length rs - 1
    mapM_ (print_rows rs) [0..n] 


Just compute the transpose with Data.List.tranpsose, then print row-by-row.

You can use transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]] [Hackage] to determine the transpose of the list of lists.
Furthermore in Haskell, one often does not work by index, just enumerate over the sublists:
import Data.List (transpose)

print_row :: Double -> IO ()
print_row = printf "%9.6f"

print_rows :: [Double] -> IO ()
print_rows = mapM_ print_row

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let rs = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
  mapM_ print_rows (transpose rs)
or simpler:
import Data.List (transpose)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let rs = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
  mapM_ (mapM_ (printf "%9.6f")) (transpose rs)

It seems you want to transpose a list of lists. This is relatively straightforward to implement, even without dipping into the library.
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose [] = []
transpose ([]:_) = []
transpose lst = hds : transpose tls
  where 
    hds = map head lst
    tls = map tail lst

Prelude> transpose [[1,2],[3,4]]
[[1,3],[2,4]]

